# Decoding HTML Entities With Python

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8, beautifulsoup

The following Python code uses BeautifulStoneSoup to fetch the LibraryThing API information for Tolkien's "The Children of Húrin".

```
import urllib2

from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup

URL = ("http://www.librarything.com/services/rest/1.0/"
            "?method=librarything.ck.getwork&id=1907912"
            "&apikey=2a2e596b887f554db2bbbf3b07ff812a")

soup = BeautifulStoneSoup(urllib2.urlopen(URL),
                          convertEntities=BeautifulStoneSoup.ALL_ENTITIES)
title_field = soup.find('field', attrs={'name': 'canonicaltitle'})
print title_field.find('fact').string
```

Unfortunately, instead of 'Húrin', it prints out 'HÃºrin'.  This is obviously an encoding issue, but I can't work out what I need to do to get the expected output.  Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the source of the web page it looks like this: `The Children of H&Atilde;&ordm;rin`. So the encoding is already broken somewhere on their side before it even gets converted to XML...

If it's a general issue with all the books and you need to work around it, this seems to work:

```
unicode(title_field.find('fact').string).encode("latin1").decode("utf-8")
```

Comment: Yup, I guess that's it.  I've contacted LibraryThing about sorting it out.  Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

The web page may be lying about its encoding. The output looks like UTF-8. If you got a str at the end then you'll need to decode it as UTF-8. If you have a unicode instead then you'll need to encode as Latin-1 first.