# How to convert html entities into symbols?

Tags: python, unicode, beautifulsoup, html-entities

I have made some adaptations to [the script from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936/using-what-ive-learned-from-stackoverflow-html-scraper/50772#50772). and I am having problems with unicode. Some of the questions end up being written poorly.

Some answers and responses end up looking like:

`Yeah.. I know.. I&#8217;m a simpleton.. So what&#8217;s a Singleton? (2)`

How can I make the `&#8217;` to be translated to the right character?

Note: If that matters, I'm using python 2.6, on a French windows.

```
>>> sys.getdefaultencoding()
'ascii'
>>> sys.getfilesystemencoding()
'mbcs'
```

---

**EDIT1:** Based on Ryan Ginstrom's post, I have been able to correct a part of the output, but I am having problems with python's unicode.

In Idle / python shell:

> Yeah.. I know.. Iâ€™m a simpleton.. So
>   whatâ€™s a Singleton?

In a text file, when redirecting stdout

> Yeah.. I know.. I’m a simpleton.. So
>   what’s a Singleton?

How can I correct that ?

---

**Edit2:** I have tried Jarret Hardie's solution but it didn't do anything.
I am on windows, using python 2.6, so my site-packages folder is at:

> C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages

There was no siteconfig.py file, so I created one, pasted the code provided by Jarret Hardie, started a python interpreter, but seems like it has not been loaded.

> > > sys.getdefaultencoding()
> > >       'ascii'

I noticed there is a site.py file at :

> C:\Python26\Lib\site.py

I tried changing the encoding in the function

```
def setencoding():
    """Set the string encoding used by the Unicode implementation.  The
    default is 'ascii', but if you're willing to experiment, you can
    change this."""
    encoding = "ascii" # Default value set by _PyUnicode_Init()
    if 0:
        # Enable to support locale aware default string encodings.
        import locale
        loc = locale.getdefaultlocale()
        if loc[1]:
            encoding = loc[1]
    if 0:
        # Enable to switch off string to Unicode coercion and implicit
        # Unicode to string conversion.
        encoding = "undefined"
    if encoding != "ascii":
        # On Non-Unicode builds this will raise an AttributeError...
        sys.setdefaultencoding(encoding) # Needs Python Unicode build !
```

to set the encoding to utf-8. It worked (after a restart of python of course).

```
>>> sys.getdefaultencoding()
'utf-8'
```

The sad thing is that it didn't correct the caracters in my program. :(

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to convert HTMl/XML entities into Unicode characters. Check out this answer in SO:

[Decoding HTML Entities With Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628332/decoding-html-entities-with-python)

Basically you want something like this:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup

soup = BeautifulStoneSoup(urllib2.urlopen(URL),
                          convertEntities=BeautifulStoneSoup.ALL_ENTITIES)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does changing your default encoding in siteconfig.py work?

In your site-packages file (on my OS X system it's in `/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/`) create a file called `siteconfig.py`. In this file put:

```
import sys
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

The setdefaultencoding method is removed from the sys module once siteconfig.py is processed, so you must put it in site-packages so that Python will read it when the interpreter starts up.