# Python encoding - Nothing works

Tags: javascript, python, encode

I've been looking the answers here in this web site, but nothing have worked so far. The problem is:

In the database, strings are saved like that one: `at &#8730;s = 7 TeV with`.

And the reason is that the "escape" JavaScript function was used.

I was not able to "unescape" these strings in Python yet. I tried to use "eval", "decode", "re.sub" and others, but without success. So please, which function can I use to get it right?

Comment: Please specify in even more detail what you have, and what youl would expect. The quoted string you have no is hard to make sense of.

Comment: That string is **not** a product of the JavaScript "escape" function. If it were, there'd be no spaces in it, and the ampersand would be encoded too.

Comment: look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/628332/decoding-html-entities-with-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string in question looks like it's encoded with HTML entities, in which case a routine like [this one](http://effbot.org/zone/re-sub.htm#unescape-html) would be appropriate for unescaping. Here's how it looks for your string:

```
>>> print unescape('at &#8730;s = 7 TeV with')
at √s = 7 TeV with
```

Answer (score 0):

[`urllib.unquote`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.unquote) should undo most if not all of the Javascript `escape()` function, but specific details on what you're getting out of `escape()` might help verify this