# How can I use Python to replace HTML escape characters?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Decode HTML entities in Python string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087370/decode-html-entities-in-python-string)

I have a string full of HTML escape characters such as `&quot;`, `&rdquo;`, and `&mdash;`.

Do any Python libraries offer reliable ways for me to replace all of these escape characters with their respective actual characters?

For instance, I want all `&quot;`s replaced with "s.

Comment: [string.replace](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.replace)

Comment: Use Beautiful Soup: http://lxml.de/elementsoup.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You want to use this:

```
try:
    from html.parser import HTMLParser  # Python 3
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    from HTMLParser import HTMLParser  # Python 2
parser = HTMLParser()
html_decoded_string = parser.unescape(html_encoded_string)
```

I also am seeing a lot of love for BeautifulSoup

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
html_decoded_string = BeautifulSoup(html_encoded_string, convertEntities=BeautifulSoup.HTML_ENTITIES)
```

Also Duplicate of these existing questions:

[Decode HTML entities in Python string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087370/decode-html-entities-in-python-string)

[Decoding HTML entities with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208916/decoding-html-entities-with-python)

[Decoding HTML Entities With Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628332/decoding-html-entities-with-python)

Comment: If you know it's a duplicate, why not flag instead of answering (other than rep)?

Comment: Its annoying when people don't take the time to look for existing answers to their questions, especially in this case - when there are so many exact replicas. However, I feel the community overflags sometimes. What if we had misunderstood the question and it really wasn't a duplicate? What if me answering the question sparked a meaningful conversation/thread that takes the question and answer in a different direction? Also its not really about the reputation, once a question is closed or deleted reputation related to it may be negated...

Comment: I only tried to warn you about the generally accepted norms of behaviour here on StackOverflow. If you seemed to care a bit, I would look up the Meta question about this, but I guess you can find it yourself if you are interested. I don't want to get into arguing about this, I was just the messenger, do it as you wish :).

Comment: With `beautifulsoup4==4.6.0` and py3, this should be `pip install beautifulsoup4` and then `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup;
html_decoded_string = BeautifulSoup(x, "lxml");
print(html_decoded_string.string)`

Comment: In Python 3 this should be `from html.parser import HTMLParser`.

Comment: As an update to @TheInitializer comment: `html.parser.HTMLParser().unescape()` is now deprecated. Use `html.unescape()` instead.