# Requests to Handle Response Encoding

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I am using `requests` to request a page. The task is very simple, but I have a problem with encoding. The page contains non-ascii, Turkish characters, but in the HTML source, the result is as below:

```
ÇINARTEPE # What it looks like
&#199;INARTEPE # What it is like in HTML source
```

So, the operations below do not return what I expected:

```
# What I have tried as encoding
req.encoding = "utf-8"
req.encoding = "iso-8859-9"
req.encoding = "iso-8859-1"

# The operations
"ÇINARTEPE" in req.text # False, it must return True
bytes("ÇINARTEPE", "utf-8") in req.content # False
bytes("ÇINARTEPE", "iso-8859-9") in req.content # False
bytes("ÇINARTEPE", "iso-8859-1") in req.content # False
```

All I want is to find out if `"ÇINARTEPE"` string is in HTML source.

#### Further Information

An example:

```
req = requests.get("http://www.eshot.gov.tr/tr/OtobusumNerede/290")
"ÇINARTEPE" in req.text # False
req.encoding = "iso-8859-1"
"ÇINARTEPE" in req.text # False
req.encoding = "iso-8859-9"
"ÇINARTEPE" in req.text # False
# Supposed to return True
```

---

#### Environment

- python 3.5.1
- requests 2.10.0

Comment: How are you handling it? Show us some code!

Comment: updated the question

Comment: Isn't it just `html.unescape("&#199;INARTEPE")`? *^checks^* yep I think that is it.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen, waiting for you to write the answer to mark as valid.

Comment: JEan PAul beat me to it, I'd rather miss out on some rep then post a duplicate answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is unescape the HTML Codes in your HTML.
There are some answers in stackoverflow already, check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11405996/how-can-i-use-python-to-replace-html-escape-characters).

But basically one method is

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
parser = HTMLParser()
html_decoded_string = parser.unescape(html_encoded_string)
```

**UPDATE**

Got a better answer from python3 [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html) and tested

```
>>> import html
>>> html.unescape("&#199;INARTEPE")
'ÇINARTEPE'
```

Comment: the OP is using "python 3.5.1" and this is the module name for python 2.  the python 3 equivalent is `html.parser`

Comment: also note that the `unescape` method was made accessible from just the `html` module so in python 3 you could really just use `import html ; html_decoded_string = html.unescape(html_encoded_string)`

Comment: I just installed and gave me `ImportError` of `markupbase` module which is in 2.x versions. @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen is right.

Comment: the odd thing is that `html.escape("ÇINARTEPE")` doesn't change it, I wonder why?

Comment: Tadhg, the answer is in `'ç' in html.entities.codepoint2name` and I guess it is related to HTML's markup symbols since it is not one of them and don't need to be escaped.